# How to test with jest & enzyme and simulate option select?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have wrote some react code and render a form, and the form doesn't have a dropdown, instead it displays all 3 options available for selecting with no default option.

I am wondering how can I test and simulate the change of option in jest using enzyme?

Below is a snippet of the code and the unit test that I have

```
import { ReactDOM } from "react";

enum SomeCategory {
  NONE = 0,
  A = 1,
  B = 2,
  C = 3
}

class ReportBase extends React.Component<{}, {}}> {
  constructor() {
    category = SomeCategory.NONE;
  }

  render() {
    return ReactDOM.div(
      {
        key: 'some-random-key', className: 'random-class-name',
      },
      [
        React.createElement(
        'select',
        {
          size: 3,
          className: 'category',
          onChange: (e: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
            this.category = parseInt(e.currentTarget.value, 10);
          },
        },
        React.createElement(
          'option',
          {value: SomeCategory.A},
          'AAA'
        ),
        React.createElement(
          'option',
          {value: SomeCategory.B},
          'BBB'
        ),
        React.createElement(
          'option',
          {value: SomeCategory.C},
          'CCC'
        )
      )
      ]
    );

const ReportForm = requireCssWithComponent(ReportBase, [
  '/static/css/some.css',
]);

export {ReportForm};
```

Below is my jest unit testing code

```
describe('ReportForm', () => {
  it('can select selection category', () => {
    spyOn(Browser, 'get_href').and.returnValue(url);
    let form = enzyme.mount(<ReportForm />);
    let react_form = form.instance().getWrappedComponent();

    form.find(`.category option[value=${SomeCategory.A}]`).simulate('click');
    expect(react_form.category).toBe(SomeCategory.A);
    form.find(`.category option[value=${SomeCategory.B}]`).simulate('click');
    expect(react_form.category).toBe(SomeCategory.B);
  });
});
```

But this failed as the expected value is different.

I believe the issue is due to the fact that onClick event doesn't work with select option, but how would I manually trigger an onChange event in jest?

Thanks for any help

Comment: What's `ReactDOM.div()`?

Comment: Oh, my bad, it is ReactDOMFactories, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dom-factories